# Pivot map[key] reversal doesn't revert the correct value

Tags: go

Extending https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39242 ...

I am trying to flatten inner slice by attaching the outer slice, then reverse the output of flatten the outer slice by attaching inner slice

https://play.golang.org/p/2tubtql5UwB

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    inner := make([]interface{}, 0)
    inner = append(inner, map[string]interface{}{"id": "1"})
    inner = append(inner, map[string]interface{}{"id": "2"})
    inner = append(inner, map[string]interface{}{"id": "3"})

    outer := make([]interface{}, 0)
    outer = append(outer, map[string]interface{}{"id": "A", "inner": inner})
    fmt.Println(outer)

    // flatten inner slice into 1 level
    pivotInners := make([]interface{}, 0)
    for _, itemOuter := range outer {
        itemOuterMap := itemOuter.(map[string]interface{})
        innerSlice := itemOuterMap["inner"].([]interface{})
        delete(itemOuterMap, "inner")
        for _, itemInner := range innerSlice {
            itemInnerMap := itemInner.(map[string]interface{})
            itemInnerMap["outer"] = itemOuterMap
            pivotInners = append(pivotInners, itemInner)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(pivotInners)

    // flatten outer slice to 1 level
    pivotOuters := make([]interface{}, 0)
    for _, pivotInner := range pivotInners {
        pivotInnerMap := pivotInner.(map[string]interface{})
        outerX := pivotInnerMap["outer"].(map[string]interface{})
        delete(pivotInnerMap, "outer")

        // dump row
        outerX["inner"] = pivotInnerMap
        fmt.Println(outerX)

        pivotOuters = append(pivotOuters, outerX)
    }

    // dump collection
    fmt.Println(pivotOuters)
}
```

**Inner slices**

```
map[id:1]
map[id:2]
map[id:3]
```

**Outer slice**

```
[map[id:A inner:[map[id:1] map[id:2] map[id:3]]]]
```

**Inner pivot**

```
[map[id:1 outer:map[id:A]] map[id:2 outer:map[id:A]] map[id:3 outer:map[id:A]]]
```

---

I am expecting

**Outer pivot**

```
[map[id:A inner:map[id:1]] map[id:A inner:map[id:2]] map[id:A inner:map[id:3]]]
```

but got

**Outer pivot**

If I echo the inner row, it returns the correct value

```
map[id:A inner:map[id:1]]
map[id:A inner:map[id:2]]
map[id:A inner:map[id:3]]
```

but after appended, the slice only got the last row

```
[map[id:A inner:map[id:3]] map[id:A inner:map[id:3]] map[id:A inner:map[id:3]]]
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is by adding a copy so each inner map doesn't refer to the same outer map.

https://play.golang.org/p/lwVuvTuwVVc

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    inner := make([]interface{}, 0)
    inner = append(inner, map[string]interface{}{"id": "1"})
    inner = append(inner, map[string]interface{}{"id": "2"})
    inner = append(inner, map[string]interface{}{"id": "3"})

    outer := make([]interface{}, 0)
    outer = append(outer, map[string]interface{}{"id": "A", "inner": inner})
    fmt.Println(outer)

    // flatten inner slice into 1 level
    pivotInners := make([]interface{}, 0)
    for _, itemOuter := range outer {
        itemOuterMap := itemOuter.(map[string]interface{})
        innerSlice := itemOuterMap["inner"].([]interface{})
        delete(itemOuterMap, "inner")
        for _, itemInner := range innerSlice {
            itemInnerMap := itemInner.(map[string]interface{})
            outerCopy := make(map[string]interface{}, len(itemOuterMap))
            for k,v := range itemOuterMap {
                outerCopy[k] = v
            }
            itemInnerMap["outer"] = outerCopy
            pivotInners = append(pivotInners, itemInner)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(pivotInners)

    // flatten outer slice to 1 level
    pivotOuters := make([]interface{}, 0)
    for _, pivotInner := range pivotInners {
        pivotInnerMap := pivotInner.(map[string]interface{})
        outerX := pivotInnerMap["outer"].(map[string]interface{})
        delete(pivotInnerMap, "outer")

        // dump row
        outerX["inner"] = pivotInnerMap
        fmt.Println(outerX)

        pivotOuters = append(pivotOuters, outerX)
    }

    // dump collection
    fmt.Println(pivotOuters)
}
```

Output

```
map[id:A inner:map[id:1]]
map[id:A inner:map[id:2]]
map[id:A inner:map[id:3]]
[map[id:A inner:map[id:1]] map[id:A inner:map[id:2]] map[id:A inner:map[id:3]]]
```

Thanks to https://github.com/200sc for answering the question on slack!